# How to remove percentage sign while using P format

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have "PercentageValue" field in SQL Server 2008, returning values like: 0.015545, 0.985554, 0.778898

I am showing this results under "percentage" column (in a table) in SSRS with the Number format = P2 (Text Box properties -> Number -> Custom -> P2), like: 1.55 %, 98.55 %, 77.88 %

I do not want to show percentage sign in the output here. How can I provide it, i couldn't find. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: make it a decimal instead of a percent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:
Text Box properties->Number->Number
and in the expression multiply your field by 100